# I want to integrate XERO to WebAPI C# Can someone provide me sample code for oauth2

Tags: c#, .net

I have tried the below

```
        XeroConfiguration xeroConfig = new XeroConfiguration();
        xeroConfig.ClientId = "****";
        xeroConfig.ClientSecret = "****";
        xeroConfig.CallbackUri = new Uri("http://localhost"); //default for standard webapi template
        xeroConfig.Scope = "openid profile email files accounting.transactions accounting.contacts offline_access";
        var client2 = new XeroClient(xeroConfig, httpClientFactory);
        var test = client2.BuildLoginUri();

        return Redirect(client2.BuildLoginUri());
```

After redirection it is giving below error
Error code: 500 Error: unauthorized_client : Invalid redirect_uri

Comment: Please post the error in your question, So someone can better assist you.

Comment: Hi It is giving Error code: 500

Error: unauthorized_client : Invalid redirect_uri

Comment: No Xero experience here, but previous work with OAuth, the provider (Xero) will need a client configuration with the redirect uri (CallbackUri) that you're providing as part of the authn/z workflow. Have you looked at the Xero web site, I'm getting hits on this subject such as https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have registered your app in the Authorization Server using a different redirect URI and in the above you are using a different redirect URI which will be validated by the Authorization Server and on mismatch, it is throwing you the Error.

You have to register your app with the Redirect URI that you will be using

Ex: If your app is running in `http://localhost:6500` and your redirect URI to receive the token and process is `http://localhost:6500/login`. You have to provide this value to the Authorization Server.

ex: The setting would look like

```
xeroConfig.CallbackUri = new Uri("http://localhost:6500/login")
```

Comment: Hi When I am hitting the Authorization URL from the Angular App It is giving CORS Errors? Any Idea ? Does XERO Supports Rest API Integration

Comment: I haven't worked with the XERO integration, however you should be having option in the XERO console to register the allowed application URLs.